# django custom validation not showing up on button click

Tags: python, django, django-validation

I wrote a custom validation for my form in forms.py but it's not working. It doesn't show anything ("email not exist"), when I press the submit button it looks like refreshing the page.
I would appreciate any help.

here is my view.py:

```
def delete(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and "DeleteButton" in request.POST:
        form = LoginPageDelete(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            DeleteData = form.cleaned_data
            q = DeleteData["emailD"]
            query = Users.objects.get(email = q )
            query.delete()
            fetch = Users.objects.all()
            return render(request,'Result.html',{'QueryDelete':fetch.values(),})

    FormDelete = LoginPageDelete()
    return render(request,'delete.html',{"FormDelete":FormDelete,})
```

here is template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Delete</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if FormDelete.errors  %}
    <p style="color:red">Please correct the problems</p>
    123
    {%endif%}

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <table>
            {{FormDelete.as_table}}
        </table>
        {%csrf_token%}
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="DeleteButton">
    </form>
</body>
```

here is forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from login.models import Users

class LoginPageDelete(forms.Form):
    emailD = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    def clean_emailD(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['emailD']
        if not Users.objects.filter(email = email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("email not exist")
        return email
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply not returning the validated form to the template. Everytime in your view, you return a new instance of LoginPageDelete() instead and discard the one with validation information.

```
def delete(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and "DeleteButton" in request.POST:
        form = LoginPageDelete(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            DeleteData = form.cleaned_data
            q = DeleteData["emailD"]
            query = Users.objects.get(email = q )
            query.delete()
            fetch = Users.objects.all()
            return render(request,'Result.html',{'QueryDelete':fetch.values(),})
    else:# here request.method is get or in your case "DeleteButton" not in request.POST
        form = LoginPageDelete()

    return render(request,'delete.html',{"FormDelete":form})
```